# Make React-redux get all data from paginated backend

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I have an application I've been developing for my company to convert data from an old system to a new one. It has a Django Rest Framework back end with a react / redux powered front end.  Functionally the program does what I want it to, but it doesn't want to pull all the data. The back end API is paginated to a page size of 200. The front end has its own pagination so it doesn't show all ~40k results at once. I do however want it to load all of those results into the props so that it can be searched for the exact item they want. This may not be the best way to go about this problem, but it's my first full stack application so it will do for now.

I have tried just removing the page size from the back end since none of my users will see it anyway. On smaller sets of data this worked fine. Once I started pulling from a larger data set however, it complains about the query parameters not matching what was expected for some reason unless I paginate.

Here is the code I believe to be relevant. If you need more please let me know.

Frontend:

```
//Get request sent out to the back end.
//Returns 200 results to my state right now
//Should be returning 40k results total and paginating 
export const getQuotes = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:8000/api/quotes/")
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_QUOTES,
        payload: res.data.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Backend:

```
#this is just the viewset used. I filter and pre-fetch some data. 
#currently on the backend I can see 200 pages of 200 results each
#as well as specify an ID to get a single detailed view
class QuoteinfoApiViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Quoteinfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuoteinfoSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset =  Quoteinfo.objects.prefetch_related('lines', 'lines__lineasm', 'lines__linemat').filter(quotedate__gte= datetime(2017,1, 1))
        return self.queryset
```

Django settings for rest framework

```
#right here is where I set the page size
#somewhere between here and the front end
#it mistakes this for me only wanting 200 results total
#even though the backend returns the proper results
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'PAGE_SIZE': 200,  

  'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 
    'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',

  'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':    'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.JsonApiPageNumberPagination',
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
  ),
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
   ),
'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.metadata.JSONAPIMetadata',
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
     'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
    ),
'ORDERING_PARAM': 'sort',

   'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
     'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),

   'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

Essentially I have a back end page size of 200. In my back end I have 200 pages with 200 items each. On my front end I have only 200 results total. Its like it only pulls the first page.